# Google Cloud node.js flexible environment

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed a node.js app as a learning tool and noticed that I'm getting billed for the project (around a $1/day).  I know node.js on Google Cloud uses Compute Engine to run the vm's, but they say the flexible environment has all the advantages of the AppEngine platform, but it seems the instances don't auto stop and start to reduce billing when not in use.

I have java project that's been running on App Engine for years and I've never been billed anything, i'm guessing that's because the instances are shutdown automatically when not in use.  So my questions are;

Is there a way to configure the flexible environment to mimic the standard environment to reduce the operating costs?

Am I miss-using something with the flexible environment?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, if not did you settle with GAE or something else ? I currently looking to deploy a puppeteer node project.

Comment: No sorry I didn't, I just went with GAE. Gyro below mentioned Heroku which runs on AWS that would have been my next choice. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Google App Engine Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing),

> Instances within the standard environment have access to a daily limit
> of resource usage that is provided at no charge defined by a set of
> quotas...
>
> Instances within the flexible environment are charged the cost of the
> underlying Google Compute Engine Virtual Machines.

According to [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/three-simple-steps-to-save-costs-when-prototyping-with-app-engine-flexible-environment-104fc6736495#.gkwl37vuz),

> Currently, the Flexible Environment needs at least one instance
> running to serve traffic and there is no free tier.

This means that at any one time, you have at least one instance running, if you're using a Flexible VM. That should explain the billing.

Please note that by default appengine launches two [g1-small](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#sharedcore) instances. Depending on your application needs, this may be an over-kill. You should [configure the compute resource settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings) in your `app.yaml` to the appropriate sizes of RAM, disk size and CPU, so as to save costs. You may also want to specify the `min_num_instances` as 1 in your [service scaling settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#services).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but my question was this: "Is there a way to configure the flexible environment to mimic the standard environment to reduce the operating costs?"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You can try to use [Google's pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) to figure out which configuration you need and how to minimize the cost of your application.

According to the calculator, the minimal cost for a flexible environment app is a little less than 40$ per month, There is nothing to do about it right now.

I eventually moved to Heruko because of that.